# InDesign - Script to find specific words between angle brackets, and copy those to a list

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

Sorry in advance if I’m not phrasing this question correctly. I know nothing about InDesign scripting, but this would solve a workflow problem I’m having at my company, so I would appreciate any and all help.

I want to find all strings in an InDesign file that are between angle brackets (i.e. <variable>) and export that out into a list. Ideally this list would be a separate document but if it can just be dumped into a text frame or something that’s fine.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thank you in advance for any and all help.

Comment: Write a script to use grep, then use the result array and export text file or create a new indesign document. This should get you started: https://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is something simple:

```
app.findGrepPreferences=NothingEnum.NOTHING; //to reset the Grep search
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = '<[^<]+?>'; //the word(s) you are searching
var fnd = app.activeDocument.findGrep (); //execute search
var temp_str = ''; //initialize an empty string
for (var i = 0; i < fnd.length; i++) { //loop through results and store the results
    temp_str += fnd[i].contents.toString() + '\r'; // add next found item text to string
}
var new_doc = app.documents.add (); //create a new document
app.scriptPreferences.measurementUnit = MeasurementUnits.POINTS; //set measurement units to points
var text_frame = new_doc.pages[0].textFrames.add({geometricBounds:[0,0,100,100]});// create a new text frame on the first page
text_frame.contents = temp_str; //output your text to the text frame in the new document
```

For more data see [here](http://jongware.mit.edu/iccs6js_html/iccs6js/index_Basics%20Suite.html).